# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'city')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to console log firebase app but it does so many errors (I have been on it for 3 hours and I am exhausted)
please help me fix this error.

I dont know why it's not working, tried to see videos on youtube and nothing helped me.

here is the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    
    const app = firebase.app();

    console.log(app)

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Firebase Hosting</title>

    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
    <!-- 
      initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
      to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
    -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

  </head>
  <body> 

    <button onclick="googleLog()">Login with google</button>


    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure it isn't

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

?

Comment: it gives me the same error...